# Earley algorithm gone wrong

Tags: grammar, context-free-grammar, earley-parser

I am trying to implement Earley's algorithm for parsing a grammar, however I must have done something wrong because after the first entry in the chart it doesn't go through the rest of the input string.
 My test grammar is the following:
S -> aXbX | bXaX 
X -> aXbX | bXaX | epsilon 
S and X are non-terminals; a and b are terminals. 
The string I want to check if it is accepted or not by the grammar is: 'abba'.

Here is my code:

```
rules = {
    "S": [
        ['aXbX'],
        ['bXaX'],
    ],
    "X" : [
        ['aXbX'],
        ['bXaX'],
        ['']
    ]
}

def predictor(rule, state):
    if rule["right"][rule["dot"]].isupper(): # NON-TERMINAL
        return [{
            "left": rule["right"][rule["dot"]],
            "right": right,
            "dot": 0,
            "op": "PREDICTOR",
            "completor": []
        } for right in rules[rule["right"][rule["dot"]]]] 
    else:
        return []


def scanner(rule, next_input):
    # TERMINAL
    if rule["right"][rule["dot"]].islower() and next_input in rules[rule["right"][rule["dot"]]]:
        print('scanner')
        return [{
            "left": rule["right"][rule["dot"]],
            "right": [next_input],
            "dot": 1,
            "op": "SCANNER",
            "completor": []
        }] 
    else:
        return []

def completor(rule, charts):
    if rule["dot"] == len(rule["right"]):
        print('completor')
        return list(map(
            lambda filter_rule: {
                "left": filter_rule["left"],
                "right": filter_rule["right"],
                "dot": filter_rule["dot"] + 1,
                "op": "COMPLETOR",
                "completor": [rule] + filter_rule["completor"]
            },
            filter(
                lambda p_rule: p_rule["dot"] < len(p_rule["right"]) and rule["left"] == p_rule["right"][p_rule["dot"]],
                charts[rule["state"]]
            )
        )) 
    else:
        return []

input_string = 'abba'
input_arr = [char for char in input_string] + ['']
charts = [[{
    "left": "S'",
    "right": ["S"],
    "dot": 0,
    "op": "-",
    "completor": []
}]]

for curr_state in range(len(input_arr)):

    curr_chart = charts[curr_state]
    next_chart = []

    for curr_rule in curr_chart:
        if curr_rule["dot"] < len(curr_rule["right"]): # not finished
            curr_chart += [i for i in predictor(curr_rule, curr_state) if i not in curr_chart]
            next_chart += [i for i in scanner(curr_rule, input_arr[curr_state]) if i not in next_chart]
        else:
            print('else')
            curr_chart += [i for i in completor(curr_rule, charts) if i not in curr_chart]

    charts.append(next_chart)

def print_charts(charts, inp):
    for chart_no, chart in zip(range(len(charts)), charts):
        print("\t{}".format("S" + str(chart_no)))
        print("\t\n".join(map(
            lambda x: "\t{} --> {}, {} {}".format(
                x["left"], 
                "".join(x["right"][:x["dot"]] + ["."] + x["right"][x["dot"]:]),
                str(chart_no) + ',',
                x["op"]
            ),
            chart
        )))
        print()
print_charts(charts[:-1], input_arr)
```

And this is the output I get (for states 1 to 4 I should get 5 to 9 entries):
S0 
S' --> .S, 0, -  
S --> .aXbX, 0, PREDICTOR 
S --> .bXaX, 0, PREDICTOR 
S1
S2
S3
S4

Comment: Ask yourself what should be in S1, and what (in S0) should cause that to happen, and then investigate (in a debugger, or with more print statements) why that isn't happening in your code.

Comment: yes, I have been trying to print here and there before posting it, but I couldn't get what I was doing wrong at all